# Использование компилятора, библиотек и хедеров из Visual Studio 2012 (или выше) в Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Добрый день!

Может быть, есть решение вести проект (редактировать, добавлять файлы) в VS 2008, а собирать его с помощью компилятора и иже с ним от VS 2012? Уж больно тормозные версии редакторов старше 2008-й.

Comment: @andrekwsc, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете на более-менее стандартном C++, *больших* проблем быть не должно. Вам придётся иметь две версии проектных файлов и поддерживать вручную соответствие, так что это дополнительный геморрой. Но вот отладку придётся всё равно вести той версией студии, на которой компилировали бинарники.

Учтите, что компилятор от 2008-й студии не настолько продвинут и не поддерживает современные фичи языка.

Тем не менее, если вы разрабатываете коммерческую программу, потратьте деньги на нормальное железо. Не экономьте на спичках.

Comment: Ммм, возможно я некорректно выразился - проект на vs 2008, есть  просто установленная vs 2012. Возможно ли такое - я беру свой проект в vs2008  и прописываю необходимые настройки - пути к компилеру, либам, хедерам, говорю Ок и студия запускает компилер и линковщик от 2012-й студии. Т.е я хочу сохранить старый интерфейс и производительность редактора, но и попробовать c++11?  Т.е vs 2012 будет просто донором нового компилятора и иже с ним - в ней ничего не будет разрабатываться.

Comment: @andrekwsc: вы имеете в виду [вот это](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105011/Using-Visual-Studio-IDE-with-Visual-C-co)?

Скорее всего, пойдёт, но у вас будут проблемы с Intellisense и всяким прочим. Если вам наплевать на удобство — попробуйте, но лучше всё же просто купите современный компьютер.